# How can you tell if a function is called synchronously or asynchronously from it's last call?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, v8

Assuming you have a function:

```
var func = function(){
    console.log(isSynchronous)
}
```

How can you tell if the function was called synchronously from its last call or asynchronously.

Ex1:

```
func() // false
func() // true
func() // true
```

Ex2:

```
func() // false
func() // true
setTimeout(function(){
   func() // false
})
```

Comment: It can’t be done as far as I know. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use the **NON STANDARD** function property `caller` For example `function one(){console.log(one.caller);two();}; function two(){console.log(two.caller)}; one();` will log `null`, then the function one as a string (same as `one.toString()`).  if the function is the top level call such as from `setTimeout(two,0)` caller will be `null`. NOTE attempting to access `caller` while in strict mode will throw a `TypeError`

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is the logic by which the first call to `func()` is false, and the second is true? Or in the second example, why is the second `func()` true? What do you mean by "synchronously from its last call"?

Comment: I am trying to attach certain properties to functions that in this example would return false.  I do not however want to attach this property to functions that in this example would return true.  I don' think that Blindman67's implementation is what I am going to use, but I think it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I have a server that is responding to requests async.  within this server, I have a function that will be called N times where N >= 1.  It currently runs a very expensive process by default and accepts a parameter 'run_expensive_process' that controls whether or not to run it.  That expensive process only needs to run one time per request to the server.  I am trying to see if I can replace the 'run_expensive_process' parameter in exchange for a way to automatically check if the function was run in the same synchronous block of code.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't have any concept of "synchronous" or "asynchronous", so there is no way to use the language to report whatever specific definition of those terms you might mean.

Just because web and node development makes heavy use of callbacks and asynchronous behavior doesn't make javascript an "asynchronous language" or whatever.

Comment: I understand that there is no built in language functionality for this, I wanted to see if there was some implementation that could be used to achieve this functionality.

Comment: it would have to be part of the library calling the function.  Also I'm curious why the answer was downvoted.   It was a yes/no question and the answer is "no".